# Feathers request WCF, single quotes vs double quotes in JSON

Tags: json, wcf, feathersjs

I am trying to call a WCF service using Feathers request framework (https://github.com/request/request) Feathers request framework is using single quotes around where as WCF is using double quotes.

```
{'name': 'Alice'} vs. {"name": "Alice"}
```

How can I get WCF to accept single quotes? 
or 
can I force Feathers request framework to use double quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add the JSON object to the JSON property of the option passed in the request. JSON is then formatted correct and the WCF service can accept the request :)

```
const option = {
  url:'http://..../NoteBasic.svc/json/SendMessageExecute',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {token: 'xxxxxxxx', message_id: 4}
};
request(option, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
  console.log(httpResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For FeathersJS, you can customize the response formatter [as documented in the Express transport API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#appconfigureexpressrestformatter). If that is really the format you need (which is invalid according to [the JSON specification](http://www.json.org/)), a forked serializer that does what you want can be found at [jcoc611/cassandraMAP](https://github.com/jcoc611/cassandraMAP) and used as a Feathers formatter through [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) like this:

```
const cassandraMAP = require("./path/to/cassandraMap");

app.configure(express.rest(function(req, res) {
  // Format the message as text/plain
  res.format({
    'application/json': function() {
      res.json(res.data);
    },
    'application/wcf-myformat': function() {
      res.end(cassandraMAP.stringify(res.data));
    }
  });  
}))
```